# Cant get field values with space from mysql using php

Tags: php

I am trying to pass variable that containing the values with space through `href` but I fail to get the expected output with space.

The code I used is:

```
print " <a href=update.php?id='$id'&name=$name&dob='$dob'&email='$email'>Update Details</a> <br>
        Student ID: $id<br> Student Name: $name<br> Date Of Birth: $dob<br> Email ID: $email<br>";
```

In **update.php** I could see the link as

```
localhost/student_portal/update.php?id='abc'&name=Giridharan
```

and I didn't get the full name and dob and email

My variables with values are as follows:

```
$id=abc
$name=Giridharan Rengarajan
$dob=1993-07-22
$email=rgiridharan.93@gmail.com
```

What should I do to get all the four values in **update.php**?

Comment: What your question has to do with mysql?

Comment: `$query_string = 'id='.urlencode($id).'&name='.urlencode($name).'&dob='.urlencode($dob).'&email='.$email;
   echo  htmlentities($query_string);
   print " <a href=update.php?htmlentities($query_string)>Update Details</a> <br>
   Student ID: $id<br> Student Name: $name<br> Date Of Birth: $dob<br> Email ID: $email<br>"; `<br> the urs i got is http://localhost/student_portal/update.php?htmlentities(id=abc&name=Giridharan+Rengarajan&dob=1993-07-22&email=rgiridharan.93@gmail.com) how can i extract values from that.?

Comment: @srain still i could not able to get the full name.

Answer (score 1):

Since spaces are not legal parts of the query string you have to encode them.

Eg:
Use rawurlencode / rawurldecode

```
<a href=update.php?id='$id'&name=rawurlencode($name)&dob='$dob'&email='rawurlencode($email)'>Update Details</a>
```

Comment: it returns only first part of my name (ie before the space)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the variables in `update.php` by:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
$dob = $_GET['dob'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
```

Answer (score 0):

For proper creation of url you can use **http_build_query**.
See examples here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Create array of your params, put it into this function and to your update script like a string.